# Call a stored procedure that act as select passing parameters and list of id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
[sp_MyProcedure]
@Param1 UniqueIdentifier,
@ListOfIds List<UniqueIdentifier>
```

How can call the stored procedure using Entity Framework 6, C# and passing the id and the list of id? This stored procedure is not an update, delete, or insert. It is just a select.

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried?  Do you already have a context with that SP represented in it?

Answer (score -1):

The entity framework designer allows you to include stored procedures when you generate the context or add them when you update from database. You can then invoke the stored process by calling the relevant  method on your DbContext object. As in

```
  DbContext myEntities = new DbContext();
  myEntities.myStoredproc(myParams);
```

However I would question why you are doing this for a select. Simple select statements should be run against your context in my opinion. That is the whole point of using EF.

Comment: Thanks. I am not generating the context from the database. I am not doing database first, I am doing a mix of code first creating my Entity configuration mapping in code, that is the reason because my current context does not have the StoredProc

Comment: Why do you want yo do this as a stored proc? Is there a good reason?

Comment: Yes it is a good reason it will do analytic calculation that uses several tables and I dont need to get all that information back

Comment: This could help? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/code-first-stored-procedure-entity-framework-6-0/